# Need the Table name in ALM where the testcase status is stored

Tags: alm

I need to run the test cases given in ALM and update the status of each test case. Can anyone tell me which TABLE in ALM Database where the test case status is stored ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different kind of status in QC (and different tables where they are stored):

- In the TEST table is a column TS_STATUS (the test execution status)
- In the TESTCYCL table is a column TC_STATUS (the test instance's execution status)
- In the RUN table is a column RUN_STATUS (the run status).

Comment: Ok thanks Man. How do i access these tables through JAVA programs ?

Comment: I don't think you should access these tables directly. Best way to access ALM from Java would be it's [REST API](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Overview.htm).